# Escaping # in gmake $(shell) function

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

I have an environment variable `GITHUB_REFS` that I want to perform some bashism on and capture the result in another variable `GITHUB_BRANCH` from a GNU makefile. My naive approach looks like this:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
GITHUB_BRANCH:=$(shell echo "${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}")
```

If I run the bashism by itself, it works fine however when running the makefile above it fails with:

```
Makefile:2: *** unterminated call to function 'shell': missing ')'.  Stop.
```

I tried escaping the `#` as `\#`, since it is a plausible culprit, and indeed then the Makefile works however the bashism does not. Double escaping it gives the same error again.

So how can I pull this off?

Comment: Have you tried defining a Make variable containing only `#`?  That's a technique that's often used for spaces and the like.  Additionally, you forgot to escape the `$` - that should be `$${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}`

Comment: Shouldn't you close the bracket before, like this ? `$(shell echo "${GITHUB_REF}#refs/heads/")`

Comment: @Tim No, the OP is attempting to use the shell's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) feature.

Comment: Then I'd suggest escaping both `$` and `#` by using `$$` and `\#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to double the dollar sign to pass it through to the shell.

```
GITHUB_BRANCH:=$(shell echo "$${GITHUB_REF\#refs/heads/}")
```

For what it's worth, this simple parameter expansion is portable to any reasonably modern `sh`, so not at all an exclusive Bash feature.

Of course, `make` is perfectly capable of performing the same substitution, without invoking an external process.

```
GITHUB_BRANCH := $(patsubst refs/heads/%,%,${GITHUB_REF})
```

Comment: FWIW, The original Bourne shell did not support that expansion syntax. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Variable_Expansion. It was first introduced, IIRC, in ksh88. However, you'd be hard pressed to find any working UNIX system where /bin/sh is really the Bourne shell rather than dash, bash, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` can be escaped using `\`, but you also forgot to escape the `$`.

This Makefile works:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

foo := $(shell echo "$${SHELL\#/bin/}")

all:
    echo $(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that this (the need to escape the `#`) is a bug, and will be fixed in an upcoming version of GNU make.  If you want to allow your makefile to be portable before/after the bug is fixed, you should hide it in a variable like this:

```
HASH := \#

foo := $(shell echo "${GITHUB_REF$(HASH)refs/heads/}")
```

This will work in all versions of GNU make.